# Create File Mapping is failing with multi-threading

Tags: c, multithreading, createfile

I am trying to map a file. It is a multi-threading program. First I do a CreateFile, which works fine, but then I do a CreateFileMapping and it fails when I use 16 threads (it returns 8, that is "Not enough storage is available to process this command".) I get no error when using 8 threads.

This is my code:

```
hFile1 = CreateFile(lpcTheFile1,
                     GENERIC_READ,
                     0,
                     NULL,
                     OPEN_EXISTING,
                     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                     NULL);

hMapFile1 = CreateFileMapping( hFile1,          // current file handle
                NULL,           // default security
                PAGE_READONLY, // read/write permission
                0,              // size of mapping object, high
                dwFileMapSize,  // size of mapping object, low
                NULL);
```

Any ideas why is it failing?

Comment: How large are the files, i.e. what is the value of `dwFileMapSize`? If you're on a 32-bit architecture, maybe 8 mappings fit into your virtual memory, but 16 mappings don't.

Comment: dwFileMapSize value is 55114, for both executions (8 threads or 16 threads).

Comment: That's rather small, so the problem likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: Does each thread call this with the same file name? Or is each thread using a different file name? When you're using 16 threads, at what point does it fail? On the 9th call? The 12th?

Comment: File names are the same, but each thread has a different directory to access its files (so each thread access different files). When I use 16 threads, it fails at the first call.